# How to Animate a Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, materials

Hello would anybody here know how to fake animate a texture/material? I would recreate a waterfall similar to this video and have a fake flowing via textures just like how it is done here without using fluid simulation. Thank you very much.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZW5yFRaQkUE at 0:49

[image]

If you must know I would recreate the animation to this scene..
[image]

Comment: For Blender Internal please see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40085/how-to-animate-texture-change-in-blender-internal

Comment: A different approach: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32214/how-can-i-create-a-flowing-rippling-water-surface-effect-that-follows-the-curve

Comment: and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object/49216#49216

Comment: or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73308/animate-a-travelling-wave-graph-view-like-an-oscilloscope